# Jenkins: signature verification failed in update site 'default' (show details)

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-pipeline

I have installed Jenkins on `Amazon EC2` instance and I am trying to get an updated list of available plugins.
When I go to `Manage Plugins --> Advanced --> Check now(at the bottom)`, I get an error as below:

> signature verification failed in update site 'default' (show details)

Answer (score 4):

Please see https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-31089 which is relevant but should be fixed on the latest builds.

For me the fix was a little different. The **java.security** file had

> jdk.certpath.disabledAlgorithms=MD2, MD5, RSA keySize < 1024

I removed MD5 from this list to make it

> jdk.certpath.disabledAlgorithms=MD2, RSA keySize < 1024

This resolved the issue for me.

Comment: where should i go and make the change in `jdk.certpath.disabledAlgorithms`  What is the name and location of the file?

Comment: The name of the file is 'java.security'. The path is likely to be different for you based on where/how you installed java. You can try the following: **sudo find / -name java.security**

Answer (score 4):

above soulution doesn't work.. but try this in java options 
https://support.cloudbees.com/hc/en-us/articles/115000494608-Why-is-there-Failed-Signature-Check-when-using-update-server-

It worked smooth for me.
-Dhudson.model.DownloadService.noSignatureCheck=true

Comment: That works. For the plugin developer that using maven, use the following command to start testing site `mvn -Dhudson.model.DownloadService.noSignatureCheck=true hpi:run`

Answer (score 1):

You can go with this path

> %JAVA_HOME%/jre/lib/security

you can find **java.security** file over here.

Comment: I don't see anything in the OP that makes me assume the server is on a Windows machine. Am I missing something?