# Signature verification failed in update site 'default' (show details)

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-groovy

I getting subjected error when trying to update plugin in Jenkins .

I have tried solution from the mentioned following link  but not working for me .

[In-App Billing, signature verification failed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18703860/in-app-billing-signature-verification-failed)

Comment: In following link: 

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34940218/jenkins-signature-verification-failed-in-update-site-default-show-details

Answer (score 0):

For me it the same thing. I try `jenkins:2.60.3` or `jenkins:2.46.1-alpine` images. Maybe they are not download plugins because they are deprecated.

It only started on
`jenkins/jenkins:lts` dockerhub image